# Steam train onboard recording advice

Tags: field-recording, vehicles, microphone

Anyone with experience recording onboard trains, more specifically steam engines, care to share their advice and or stories? I might get a chance to record on one soon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen these?

http://sepulchra.com/blog/?p=1785

http://sepulchra.com/blog/?p=1749

http://sepulchra.com/blog/?p=1760

Comment: Thanks @steve urban. The antique machine library is definitely on my must buy list! Great sounding whistles too, I'll have to hit up Michael and see if he'd sell or trade some sounds for them.

Comment: While I'm certain Michael would love the sale, I was thinking more along the lines of the information he had in the posts. I'm certain he'd have more tips if you reached out to him too. In fact, where is @sepulchra?